# Keyword argument in unpacking argument list/dict cases in Python

Tags: python, argument-passing

For python, I could use unpacking arguments as follows.

```
def hello(x, *y, **z):
    print 'x', x
    print 'y', y
    print 'z', z

hello(1, *[1,2,3], a=1,b=2,c=3)
hello(1, *(1,2,3), **{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3})
```

```
x =  1
y =  (1, 2, 3)
z =  {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

But, I got an error if I use keyword argument as follows.

```
hello(x=1, *(1,2,3), **{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3})
```

```
TypeError: hello() got multiple values for keyword argument 'x'
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regardless of the order in which they are specified, positional arguments get assigned prior to keyword arguments. In your case, the positional arguments are `(1, 2, 3)` and the keyword arguments are `x=1, a=1, b=2, c=3`. Because positional arguments get assigned first, the parameter `x` receives 1 and is not eligible for keyword arguments any more. This sounds a bit weird because syntactically your positional arguments are specified *after* the keyword argument, but nonetheless the order “positional arguments → keyword arguments” is always adhered to.

Here is a simpler example:

```
>>> def f(x): pass
... 
>>> f(1, x=2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() got multiple values for keyword argument 'x'
>>> f(x=2, *(1,))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() got multiple values for keyword argument 'x'
```