# Python KeyError when converting list of list to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, keyerror

I'm stuck with this simple task. I have a list of lists and I need to convert it to a dictionary but so far without any success.

I tried it with the code below, but it gives me KeyError:0

```
list = [[3,0,7,4,5],[2,3,0,1,2],[6,6,7,6,6]]

d = {}
for x in list:
    i = 0
    for number in x:
        d[i].append(number)
        i += 1
```

I need it to be like this:

```
{0: [3,2,6], 1: [0,3,6], 2: [7,0,7], 3: [4,1,6], 4: [5,2,6]}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Avoid naming an array `list`. It can get mixed up with the function `list()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as a side note, you can do this quite simply by using the `enumerate` and `zip` functions.

```
lst = [[3, 0, 7, 4, 5], [2, 3, 0, 1, 2], [6, 6, 7, 6, 6]]
d = dict(enumerate(zip(*lst)))
```

- `zip(*lst)` is basically a *transpose* function. It returns a list in Python 2, or a `zip` object in Python 3, which can be converted into the equivalent list.

  ```
  [(3, 2, 6), (0, 3, 6), (7, 0, 7), (4, 1, 6), (5, 2, 6)]
  ```
- `enumerate()` basically just tacks the index of an element before it, and returns an `enumerate` object, which when converted into a list returns a list of tuples.

  ```
  [(0, (3, 2, 6)), (1, (0, 3, 6)), (2, (7, 0, 7)), (3, (4, 1, 6)), (4, (5, 2, 6))]
  ```
- `dict()` takes a list of tuples and turns them into key/value pairs.

  ```
  {0: (3, 2, 6), 1: (0, 3, 6), 2: (7, 0, 7), 3: (4, 1, 6), 4: (5, 2, 6)}
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Please don't use built-ins as IDs.

```
>>> lst = [[3, 0, 7, 4, 5], [2, 3, 0, 1, 2], [6, 6, 7, 6, 6]]
```

You're getting the `KeyError` the first time you call:

```
d[i].append(number)
```

This is because there is no key `i` in `d`. Rather than fix up this code, let's look at using [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), which is perhaps more "Pythonic":

```
>>> d = dict(enumerate(zip(*lst)))
>>> d
{0: (3, 2, 6), 1: (0, 3, 6), 2: (7, 0, 7), 3: (4, 1, 6), 4: (5, 2, 6)}
```

Perhaps this is a little daunting for a new Python user. Let me break it down.

```
>>> zip(*lst)
[(3, 2, 6), (0, 3, 6), (7, 0, 7), (4, 1, 6), (5, 2, 6)]
```

This [unpacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141152/keyword-argument-in-unpacking-argument-list-dict-cases-in-python) the list into [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), which "zips" the three smaller lists together.

```
>>> enumerate(zip(*lst)
```

This returns an iterator of pairs. Each pair is an index (starting with 0) and an item from the input.

```
>>> dict(enumerate(zip(*lst)))
```

The [`dict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) function returns a new dictionary object, initialised with the key-value pairs passed in.